# Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp' - why?

Tags: .net, xml

I have the following line of code:

```cs
XDocument formConfiguration = XDocument.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLFileURL"]);
```

I get the following exception message:

> Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'

There are no `&nbsp;` sequences in the XML.  There are no `&` characters in the XML. Where could this be coming from?

Thanks,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

Could it be there *was* an `&nbsp;` declaration, which is an issue, because ampersand (&) isn't allowed for XML documents?

Comment: You could mention changing &nbsp; to &amp;nbsp; for conformance.

Comment: There are no space entities in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer; XDocument.Load works better with a file path rather than a URL.  It works now.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

it looks like there *should* be an `&nbsp;` in your file. I'd recommend using an XML validator to make sure that the XML file you are trying to read is well-formed. [W3Schools has one here](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_validator.asp)

Comment: Both the XML file I'm trying to load, and the web.config of my application containing the relevant appSettings section, both come out clean.

Comment: Have you done a text search for 'nbsp'? Are there any characters that match that string in your XML?

Comment: None.  The string doesn't exist within the XML.

Comment: what's the value of the app setting XMLFileUrl? Is it fully qualified? I don't think it should matter, but wouldn't hurt to try just for testing