# Reading XML from webBrowser control

Tags: c#, xml, browser

I am trying to load the XML like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.LoadXml(webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString());
```

I always get this an `XmlException` thrown, with the message `Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 73, position 18.` each time.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and what I can do to prevent this, the XML page is dynamically generated each time using PHP and it reads cookies which have been added previously when the user is logged in.

Comment: Check out this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039476/reference-to-undeclared-entity-nbsp-why

Comment: @SteveDanner, I have been searching previously before I posted this and I did come across that, I don't see a `nbsp` or an `&` in the file though.

Comment: Well, can you post line 73 of the document so we can see it?

Comment: There isn't a line 73, not sure why the error says that there is an error there, I updated the main post with the 2 possible pages which are displayed and are being read.

Comment: Why don't you try replacing all &nbsp; for blank space before loading the XML using a RegEx, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708734/how-to-replace-nbsp-to-space)? By the way, loading those sample documents don't generate any exceptions to me. There must be some &nbsp; somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
doc.LoadXml(webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString());
```

with:

```
doc.LoadXml(webBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " "));
```

Comment: The answer should stop all the `&nbsp;` errors, but it won't fix other errors.